# Nav bar does not work when I place a div element before it

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a banner above my nav bar but when I do, my anchor tags do not work and do not even show a pointer cursor when you hover over them. However when I remove this div everything seems to work fine. Is there something I am missing?

```css
section {
  padding: 4em 5em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
}

strong{
  display: block;
}

.top_banner{
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(../IMG/mountain.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% -80%;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
}

.banner_title{
  margin: 0;
  font-family: var(--font-fancy);
  font-size: var(--font-size-h3);
}

.nav_bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background: var(--colour-light);
  width: 100%;
}

.nav_items{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
}
.landing_page{
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="top_banner">
  <h2 class="banner_title">Yassin</h2>
  <p class="profession"> Mechanical Engineer</p>
</div>

<!-- Landing Page -->
<header class="landing_page">
  <div class="nav_bar">
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav_items">
        <li><a href="../../../Portfolio_Site/HTML/Portfolio_Site.html"> About Me </a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <section class="introduction">
    <div class="background_text">
      <h1> Mechanical Engineer </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="intro">
      <h1> Hi, <span class="exclamation"> I am</span> <strong> Yassin Gubara.  </strong> </h1>
    </div>
    <img src="../IMG/001.svg" class="filled_squares"/>
    <img src="../IMG/002.SVG" class="outline_square"/>
  </section>
</header>
```

Comment: I guess there is a problem with CSS positioning. Will you share your `css` code too, please?

Comment: Ah yeah, just added it

Comment: I don't see any issue...

Comment: Could it be a problem with the browser? Using Safari

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top_banner">
        <h2 class="banner_title">Yassin</h2>
        <p class="profession"> Mechanical Engineer</p>
      </div>
  
      <!-- Landing Page -->
      <header class="landing_page">
        <div class="w3-content">
            <img class="mySlides" src="https://i.imgur.com/ZtdhrUA.jpg" alt="custom_html_banner1" style="width:100%">
            <img class="mySlides" src="https://i.imgur.com/ZtdhrUA.jpg" alt="custom_html_banner2" style="width:100%">
            <img class="mySlides" src="https://i.imgur.com/ZtdhrUA.jpg" alt="custom_html_banner3" style="width:100%">
            <img class="mySlides" src="https://i.imgur.com/ZtdhrUA.jpg" alt="custom_html_banner4" style="width:100%">
            <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
            <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
           </div>
          <div class="nav_bar">
            <nav>
              <ul class="nav_items">
                  <li><a href="../../../Portfolio_Site/HTML/Portfolio_Site.html"> About Me </a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
  
          <section class="introduction">
            <div class="background_text">
              <h1> Mechanical Engineer </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="intro">
              <h1> Hi, <span class="exclamation"> I am</span> <strong> Yassin Gubara.  </strong> </h1>
            </div>
            <img src="../IMG/001.svg" class="filled_squares"/>
            <img src="../IMG/002.SVG" class="outline_square"/>
          </section>
        </header>
</body>
</html>
```

It is working

Comment: There is some additional content you added that makes it hard to see when I include my css file but it is still not working on my side

Comment: try it in another environment, like https://www.w3schools.com/tryit/ If here it works but in your env not, it might have to do with some variable names clashing from the library you import. Try using other class names

Comment: @YasinGubara It is working when I added your css

Comment: @YasinGubara it is working here: [link](https://codepen.io/ammarmohib/pen/JjJyzgE)